# Should you hardcode texture coordinates array in vertex shader when possible?

Tags: performance, opengl, memory, shader

So i have made a voxel engine where instead of passing texture coordinates array to VAO, i hardcode that array in vertex shader:

```cpp
const vec2 texcoords[4] = vec2[4](
    const vec2(1.0, 1.0),
    const vec2(1.0, 0.0),
    const vec2(0.0, 0.0),
    const vec2(0.0, 1.0)
);
```

And instead i pass vertexIndex to VAO (so vertexIndex determines which index of this array to use).
so it saves me up a LOT of memory, i could fit every info about each voxel in single uint. but i want to know what downsides does this method have, should i use this when memory profit is not as much?

EDIT:
*here is code for chunk.vert:*

```c
#version 460 core

in uint vertex;
out vec2 pass_texcoord;

out float pass_faceLight;
uniform mat4 projection;
uniform mat4 view;
uniform uint texAtlasRowsCount;
uniform vec3 chunkPos;
    
#define vertexIndex (vertex & 0x600000) >> 21
#define xc (vertex & 0x3F)
#define yc ((vertex & 0xFC0) >> 6)
#define zc ((vertex & 0x3F000) >> 12)
#define light ((vertex & 0x1C0000) >> 18) * 0.2F
#define pos vec4(vec3(xc, yc, zc) + chunkPos, 1)
#define position projection * view * pos

const vec2 texcoords[4] = vec2[4](
    const vec2(1.0, 1.0),
    const vec2(1.0, 0.0),
    const vec2(0.0, 0.0),
    const vec2(0.0, 1.0)
);

void main() {
    uint row = ((vertex & 0x3F800000) >> 23) - 1;
    const uint col = row / texAtlasRowsCount;
    row %= texAtlasRowsCount;

    pass_texcoord = texcoords[vertexIndex];
    pass_texcoord.x += row;
    pass_texcoord.y += col;

    pass_texcoord /= texAtlasRowsCount;

    //float AmbientOclussion = float((vertex & 0xC0000000) >> 30);

    pass_faceLight = light;

    gl_Position = position;
}
```

Comment: I misread your initial question and was under the impression that you were hard-coding the UVs on the CPU side, not the GPU. I've deleted my answer as it is incorrect.

Comment: So you basically have a texture for each face? I can see you're already using a texture atlas so your texture buffering performance should be good. The only thing I can think of is not being able to use a single texture per voxel/block which can be more work when creating art.

Comment: @MudkipHacker That can be mitigated by using a image composition tool like ImageMagick. It's great for composing single-texture tiles into a texture atlas. The art can be created as individual faces and then composited together during a build step.

Comment: i don't have a texture for each face, how do i achive that, just pass face id (so if id = bottom, use bottom tex)?

Comment: @NameThatDisplays I think that's a possible solution. If you think about it, if you're already passing in a index and a faceId, what's the advantage of that over just using just texture uv? Down the road, you might have even more vertex data you need to add and this memory saving might becomes not worth the hassle.